# Save changes in editable data grid with enter key - xpages

Tags: datagrid, xpages

I have a data grid that displays on my xPage.  I allow the user to edit two of the fields in the grid.  I would like either field to recognize the user hitting the enter key and automatically save those line changes to its document.  I don't want to use a button for the user to manually click.  Can someone explain how I can do that with a code snippet?  Thanks.

Mike

Comment: Mike, you can capture the keypress event for the Enter key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike,

In your edit fields, you can have code like this. Note that keyCode #13 is the enter key. You can find out the keycode of specific keyboard keys using http://keycode.info/

You would likely want to execute serverside code to save your document. I haven't every tried using the keycode in SSJS, so I can't say it works for sure.  But the keypress event is the way to go for what you are trying to accomplish.

```
var keyCode = event.keyCode;
if(keyCode == 13){
    //Save here
}else{
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

[image]

---

If the UI doesn't make it easy to add the keypress event, you can still add it to the source. It has to be on an editable input field to work.

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onkeypress" submit="true" id="eventHandler1" refreshMode="partial">

<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var keyCode = event.keyCode;
   if(keyCode == 13){
      //Save here
   }else{
      event.returnValue = false;
   }}]]></xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

Comment: Steve, where do I put the code?  The edit fields don't have events as they are Data Grid Columns.

Comment: So it would go in the source for the DataGridColumn?

Comment: It only works with an editable field. You said in your question that "you allow the user to edit two of the fields".  I made the assumption that there is a control in the data grid column that is editable. That control is where you attach the onkeypress event.

Comment: YEs, two of the columns are editable but actually they aren't "fields", they're columns but still editable.  I'll try it in the column.  I'll also try making the grid and enhanced grid....Thinking about though, I don't have a document handle.  The grid uses the entry variable.

Comment: Mike, you should edit your question and add your code. This will help me to know if/where to attach the event.

Comment: I tried some things so I'll show you what I did if I can remember them all.  In datagrid props,  onkeypress

Comment: I tried some things so I'll show you what I did if I can remember them all.  In datagrid properties:, changed dojoType to "dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid",  in onkeypress

editedRowsArray=[-1];
var keyCode = event.keyCode;
var args = {
 onError:function() {alert('error - changes not saved');}
}

if(keyCode == 13){
    restServiceObj.save(args);
}else{
    event.returnValue = false;
}
restServiceObj.close();
gridObj._refresh();

ADDED OUTPUT SCRIPT - "value"
var editedRowsArray = [];

Something is wrong though as now I don't see the documents when I preview.

Comment: I have this code in the onKeyPress event.....var vkeyCode1 = event.keyCode;
if(vkeyCode1 != 13){
    event.returnValue = false;
}else{.........................but it's returning the error: " [ReferenceError] 'event' not found"........It was working and then it stopped.  HELP???

Comment: Are you sure that the code is in the clientside?  If it was working, but then stopped, the issue could be related to something else you did in the project.

Comment: No, it's server side.  I'm saving a document and refreshing the screen.  Client side doesn't do that.

Comment: `keypress`, `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are all deprecated. `keydown` and `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also make the code easier to understand. Just keep in mind some old browsers used some non-standard codes, so left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE and Legacy Edge they would be `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 